# Some websites to learn about MySQL tables and creating databases (The Do's and Don'ts)

Tags: mysql, database

I am venturing on making a website with a database for baseball games for an intramural league. I have made databases before, but this project seems to have many fields that will require at least 3 tables.

I want to make the tables correct, so that I can sort and gather information from multiple fields properly ( such as the team table querying total goals scored ). Is there a website where there is a MySQL tutorial on do's and don'ts for making somewhat complex databases?

Not intro tutorials, but more around where you get into combining multiple pieces of information correctly. Any source would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This may help you. It is top [20 best practices](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/) when dealing with MySQL.